# How to take data into piechart from database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created table and on click of view button in each row a modal opens that have the pie chart with no of leaves taken by people till date in categories like sick, vacation, maternity, paternity for the particular year.Please help me how to take data from database..and on click of 1st button the pie chart shows up

[image]

but if I click on any button other than 1st then I get a blank page.

[image]

```
 <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm view" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#{{pl.id}}_3"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" style="color:black"></i></button>
       <!-- Modal -->
       <div class="modal fade" id= "{{pl.id}}_3" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
           <!-- Modal content-->
             <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title"><b>{{pl.employee.emp_name|title }}</b> Leave Details</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                   <p>Applied leave from {{pl.start_date}} to {{pl.end_date}} for {{ pl.end_date|timeuntil:pl.start_date }} </p>
                   <p>Leave applied on : {{pl.date_created}}</p>
                   <p><div id="container" class="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div></p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </td>
```

My jquery Code:

```
 $(document).on('click','.view', function(e){
      Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
        },
      title: {
        text: 'Total number of leaves applied till now'
             },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
               },
      plotOptions: {
           pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                 style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                        }
                     }
                }
             },
               series: [{
                 name: 'Brands',
                 colorByPoint: true,
             data: [{
                 name: 'Sick Leaves',
                 y: 56.33
                   }, {
                name: 'Casual Leaves',
                y: 24.03,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
                  }, {
               name: 'Vacation Leaves',
               y: 10.3
                  }, {
               name: 'Maternity Leaves',
               y: 4.77
                  }, {
               name: 'Paternity Leaves',
               y: 0.91
            }]
          }]
       });
     });
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: Please provide a https://jsfiddle.net example

Comment: Yes..These are the errors in console.. https://ibb.co/mKa9Ya

Comment: HighCharts Adapter is not defined in console..Is it causing any problem?

Answer (score -1):

Modal fade has some time delay so you have to call your function by using set time out

create a new function and call it `setTimeout(function(){ myFunc(); }, 500);` This will work on your modal.

Comment: Using setTimeout to fix that kind of problems is usually not the correct solution and can create race condition.